# python: rayleigh fit (histogram)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, histogram, curve-fitting

I’m still approaching programming in python.
For the first time i'm trying working with histograms and fit!

In particular, i have a dataset and i made a histogram of it. At this point i should do a rayleigh fit but i can't figure out the correct way to set the parameters correctly.  I read that loc and scale, which should be the parameters of fit are usually set as 0 and 1. Obviously, in this way, the fit doesn’t work well!!! Is there someone who can help me?
To be clear I'am attaching the code I am using.

Thank you.

```
import os 
import numpy as np
import nrrd
import nibabel as nib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import SimpleITK as sitk
import scipy.stats
from scipy.stats import rayleigh
import math


#fit

# Sample from this Random variable
x0 = np.array(fondi)

# Adjust Distribution parameters
loc, scale = stats.rayleigh.fit(x0) # (9.990726961181025, 
4.9743913760956335)

# Tabulate over sample range (PDF display):
xl = np.linspace(x0.min(), x0.max())

# Display Results:
fig, axe = plt.subplots()

axe.hist(x0,density=1, label="background")

axe.plot(xl,stats.rayleigh(scale=scale, loc=loc).pdf(xl), label="Rayleigh")
axe.set_title("Distribution Fit")
axe.set_xlabel("Intensità")

axe.legend()
axe.grid()
```

my data (fondi) are this:[13 15 13 14 12 13 12 14 15 12 11 10 11 15 18 11 11 11 13 15 15 15 11 12
13 12 15 15 15 12 12 11 14 16 11 13 14 16 17 24 21 16 20 18 18 19 21 22
19 15 16 15 13 14 16 18 21 19 22 14 13 14 15 14 17 19 17 16 18 12 15 17
17 16 17 16 19 17 14 13 16 16 13 15 17 17 20 18 17 12 19 14 15 15 14 13
17 16 14 12 11 12 20 19 16 24 19 20 19 17 16 17 16 19 22 17 16 20 22 21
22 20 14 18 16 19 20 17 20 22 20 22 19 17 13 16 18 14 16 20 20 18 19 19
16 19 12 12 14 14 13 15 16 16 19 16 17 12 11 11 10 12 11 11 13 14 13 17
8  8  8 10 10 10 14 16 11  9  9 11 10 17 13 15 19 15 13 16 17 14 12 13
14 11 10 15 13 12 12 11 10  9  9  9  9  8 15 16 12  9 11  9 10 10  7  7
7 21 19 13 10 15 12 10 10  9  8 10 20 14 13 11 13 15 14 10 11 12 16 17
15 12 13 16 15 13 14 17 14 13 15 13 11 14 15 17 18 22 21 16 17 22 17 17
18 26 17 19 21 16 15 19 19 22 19 18 17 18 18 12 17 17 17 18 14 16 20 17
16 16 18 16 19 18 18 20 18]

OUTPUT: loc=6.783540954380711 scale=6.430045149216335

[image: Rayleight fit]

Comment: Always provide a [mre] **with imports, data, errors, current output, and expected output**. Only plot images are okay. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: 0 and 1 are the _default_ parameters for that distribution. You would need to _fit_ those parameters based on your data. See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit). As mentioned above, please include a complete example, I'm assuming you're using `scipy.stats` here.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What do you mean by fit? Adjusting a distribution to data to find out parameters? Could you provide a MCVE we lack imports, input and expected output.

Comment: @bnaecker yes i'm using scipy.stats. I add the "import" and the list (fondi) that i'm using for the histogram. Thank you

Comment: @jlandercy I mean that i want adjusting a distribution to data to find out parameters. I try to add an example. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Adjustment MCVE

Below a simple procedure to draw a trial dataset from a [Rayleigh distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit) and then find its parameters using [Maximum Likelihood Estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) provided by the [`scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit) method:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a Continuous Variable: 
X = stats.rayleigh(loc=10, scale=5)

# Sample from this Random variable
x0 = X.rvs(size=10000, random_state=123)

# Adjust Distribution parameters
loc, scale = stats.rayleigh.fit(x0) # (9.990726961181025, 4.9743913760956335)

# Tabulate over sample range (PDF display):
xl = np.linspace(x0.min(), x0.max(), 100)

# Display Results:
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.hist(x0, density=1, label="Sample")
axe.plot(xl, X.pdf(xl), label="Exact Distribution")
axe.plot(xl, stats.rayleigh(scale=scale, loc=loc).pdf(xl), label="Adjusted Distribution")
axe.set_title("Distribution Fit")
axe.set_xlabel("Variable, $x$ $[\mathrm{AU}]$")
axe.set_ylabel("Density, $f(x)$ $[\mathrm{AU}^{-1}]$")
axe.legend()
axe.grid()
```

It renders as follow:

[image]

### Notes

I would like to draw your attention on some key points:

- 300 is a huge number for histogram bins, it will lower the quality of the representation as you will have empty or low populated bins. It can also make statistical tests (such as Chi Square Goodness of Fit) fails due to bins under representativity. You certainly may let `matplotlib` estimate the number of bins;
- Distribution generally takes location and scale parameters, in `scipy.stats` they do their best to normalize - when possible - every available distribution in that way. To find out the correspondence with [usual parametric distribution definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution), you need to solve the following problem: `pdf(x) = pdf(y)/scale` where `y = (x-loc)/scale`. In this case you will see than the `scale` parameter is equivalent to `sigma` and this is invariant to origin shift (not dependent of the `loc` value);
- To adjust a distribution you need to perform some analytical/statistical procedure at some point to estimate parameters from sampled data. This part is missing in your code (see `stats.rayleigh.fit(x0)` in the MCVE above). This part is independent of any graph plotted by `matplotlib`, it is handled by `scipy` which performs MLE on the complete dataset (this is why changing the bins on only affects the histogram display and nothing else).

#### Update

Based on your post update, I complete my answer. Using the dataset you provided:

```
x0 = np.array([13, 15, 13, 14, 12, 13, 12, 14, 15, 12, 11, 10, 11, 15, 18, 11, 11, 11, 13,
               15, 15, 15, 11, 12, 13, 12, 15, 15, 15, 12, 12, 11, 14, 16, 11, 13, 14, 16,
               17, 24, 21, 16, 20, 18, 18, 19, 21, 22, 19, 15, 16, 15, 13, 14, 16, 18, 21,
               19, 22, 14, 13, 14, 15, 14, 17, 19, 17, 16, 18, 12, 15, 17, 17, 16, 17, 16,
               19, 17, 14, 13, 16, 16, 13, 15, 17, 17, 20, 18, 17, 12, 19, 14, 15, 15, 14,
               13, 17, 16, 14, 12, 11, 12, 20, 19, 16, 24, 19, 20, 19, 17, 16, 17, 16, 19,
               22, 17, 16, 20, 22, 21, 22, 20, 14, 18, 16, 19, 20, 17, 20, 22, 20, 22, 19,
               17, 13, 16, 18, 14, 16, 20, 20, 18, 19, 19, 16, 19, 12, 12, 14, 14, 13, 15,
               16, 16, 19, 16, 17, 12, 11, 11, 10, 12, 11, 11, 13, 14, 13, 17, 8, 8, 8, 10,
               10, 10, 14, 16, 11, 9, 9, 11, 10, 17, 13, 15, 19, 15, 13, 16, 17, 14, 12, 13,
               14, 11, 10, 15, 13, 12, 12, 11, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 15, 16, 12, 9, 11, 9, 10,
               10, 7, 7, 7, 21, 19, 13, 10, 15, 12, 10, 10, 9, 8, 10, 20, 14, 13, 11, 13, 15,
               14, 10, 11, 12, 16, 17, 15, 12, 13, 16, 15, 13, 14, 17, 14, 13, 15, 13, 11, 14,
               15, 17, 18, 22, 21, 16, 17, 22, 17, 17, 18, 26, 17, 19, 21, 16, 15, 19, 19, 22,
               19, 18, 17, 18, 18, 12, 17, 17, 17, 18, 14, 16, 20, 17, 16, 16, 18, 16, 19, 18,
               18, 20, 18])
```

We can try to adjust a Rayleigh distribution:

```
p = stats.rayleigh.fit(x0)
X = stats.rayleigh(*p)
```

Visually, the fit is not that good:

[image]

Let's confirm it by statistical tests. First we can check if the [ECDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) is compatible with the CDF of the adjusted distribution using the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) [Test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html):

```
kst = stats.kstest(x0, X.cdf)
# KstestResult(statistic=0.12701044409231593, pvalue=0.0001232197856051324)
```

We can also assess expected counts for the adjusted distribution and compare them to the osberved one using the [Chi Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) [Test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html):

```
c, b = np.histogram(x0)
ct = np.diff(X.cdf(b))*np.sum(c)
c2t = stats.chisquare(c, ct, ddof=2)
# Power_divergenceResult(statistic=31.874916914227434, pvalue=4.284273564311872e-05)
```

Difference of Degrees of freedom is equal to two because in addition of Chi Square statistics we had to estimate the `loc` and `scale` parameters of the Rayleigh distribution (hence `ddof=2` in the test call).

Both tests have very low and similar [p-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value), it means it is very unlikely that null hypothesis are met (thus it tell us we should reject them):

- **Kolmogorov:** `H0` = The sample is drawn from the reference distribution;
- **Chi Square:** `H0` = There are no differences between the classes in observed and expected distribution;

It is then hard to believe than your dataset comes from the adjusted Rayleigh distribution.

You can compare those results with the synthetic data drawn in the MCVE, tests returns p-value above 10%:

```
# KstestResult(statistic=0.0097140857969642, pvalue=0.3019167138216704)
# Power_divergenceResult(statistic=11.170065854104491, pvalue=0.13137094282775724)
```

It that scenario we could not reject H0's, we are confident in the fact sampled data may come from the adjusted Rayleigh distribution.

Comment: Thank you very much: it works! I have another question... I'm trying to understand why if i change the bins number the adjusted distribution doesn't change?
And is there a way to exstimate the sigma of the distribution?
Thank you again for your help!!!!!!!!

Comment: Because MLE performs on all data. Have a look to the code, the histogram part is not linked to the fit part. Matplotlib just renders and scipy adjusts. They are independent processes. Wikipedia has good explanation about Maximum Likelihood Estimation. I am glad it solved your issue, you may mark it as an answer if you feel it is appropriate.

Comment: @ClaudiaFalzi, About the sigma, as stated in documentation distribution are normalized. You need to substitute z=(x-loc)/scale in the normalized pdf then make it match the usual parametric distribution to get the sigma value. You also need to check that it is compatible with an origin shifted (could you post the value of loc and scale you have got with your dataset?). I will update my post later on to reflect that aspect

Comment: @ClaudiaFalzi, I have updated my post to address your question. Let me know if it is clear enough for you. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand if my "scale" is the sigma. I'm attaching a new part of the code in my post!!! Can you explane me in which way i can understand?

Comment: @ClaudiaFalzi, Based on your data, it is hard to tell it is a Rayleigh distribution, see statistical test in my updated answer. About parameters (eg. sigma), you need to do some math and solve the following problem: `your_pdf(x) = scipy_pdf(z=(x-loc)/scale)/scale`. For a Rayleigh distribution (wikipedia vs scipy): `sigma=scale`. Cheers